# How to prevent timeout error when importing large CSV data set into Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm trying to load a rather large CSV file. It has more than 700K entries and it times out every time when I try to import the data.

I am currently using `for` loop over the data to load it but it's quite time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing the query execution timeout flag in your configuration settings:

```
-query-execution-timeout-sec=180
```

The default setting is 180 seconds. You can set a larger value. If you set it to 0 there will be no time limit for query execution.